# Do shore excursions need to be purchased in advance on cruises?

Tags: cruising, alaska, shore-excursions

I'd like to do some shore excursions on a cruise I'm considering. Do the excursions need to be purchased in advance or should they be purchased once you're on the cruise or what?

Additionally, I was thinking about paying for the cruise via expedia.com. If the excursions need to be purchased in advance, would I still be able to purchase them if I used expedia.com?

Comment: It will depend on the cruise. With big cruises there may be limited availability, so you'd have to book in advance to get the excursions you want. A lot can be bought when onboard too.

Comment: Frame-question: Do you need to buy them from the cruise? In my experience (6 cruises) excursions bought from the cruise are waaaay more expensive and usually you can just disembark and buy the same ones in the shore much cheaper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. No, Shore Excursions can be bought right up to the time the tour leaves.  However, for popular excursions, availability might be a bigger issue.

Many cruise lines will have shore ex staff on the pier to do last minute sign ups.

2. No, Expedia will take payment for your cruise fare only.  In almost all cases, you will have to either call the cruise line or logon to their site to complete your reservation.

You can book excursions at that time, usual 90 days before sailing.  On their site, you can also reserve many other onboard activities

Comment: My parents were on a cruise recently and well before the second port day, all shore excursions were sold. I claim bad management, not enough places available. (And they were pretty expensive in my view.)

Comment: An economist might suggest that if they were all sold up by the second port day then they weren't expensive enough, @Willeke .

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the excursion actually, but most should be bookable at least until the day before. The following is what I could experience so far in my past cruises.

Adventure-typed excursions such as canyoning or rafting often have strict limitations because the local correspondent may have that many pieces of equipment available to equip participants, and they must limit the size of groups so that there is enough staff to look after the one-day adventurers for their safety. Also happen with speedboats, panoramic trains, any specialty transportation mode that has limited seats; they can sell out days in advance.

If there is transportation involved, and it is specific to the cruise ship, the shore excursion desk usually calls a local tour bus company the night before to order the correct number of buses depending on how many passengers have signed up. Same-day walk-ins for those may or may not work depending on remaining capacity on the bus.

Walking tours that start from the pier (no bus transfer in-between) are easy to join on last minute. Same goes for activities that cater to any tourist in the area and run independently of the cruise ship presence such as museums, hop-on-hop-off local bus are virtually unlimited in capacity. Your so-called excursion may be a simple voucher you exchange for admission to the local attraction; you may even be on your own to get there.

For attractions that can be joined locally within walking distance or by using local public transportation, you can even save money by getting ashore on your own and buy your admission there. Cruise lines take a big cut on excursions! If the ship is docked in some remote area from the city, there is a shuttle service set up for all passengers that drops you off at some more practical place to start exploring on your own. The details are told in the daily newsletter delivered to your cabin. Can be free or offered for a small amount.

Just make sure you make it back to the ship before the all-aboard time; missing the ship is something you definitely want to avoid at all costs.
Going for a cruise-line-organized excursion offers some peace-of-mind on this point: if the bus is stuck in traffic on the return leg, the ship waits.